# undefined method `before_action' for ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, before-filter

Trying to attach file to mail via before_action filter:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  before_action :add_logo_attachment

  layout 'mail'
  default from: "\"Admin\" <admin@site.com>",
      to: Proc.new {Admin.pluck(:email)}

  def send_mail
    mail(subject: 'Hello, admin!')
  end
  .
  .
  private

  def add_logo_attachment
    attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.read(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/logo.png'))
  end

end
```

And I get this error: undefined method `before_action' for UserMailer:Class
There is the same example in Rails guides and I can't understand what's the difference between my code and the code in guides.

Comment: if you're using rails 3, use `before_filter` instead of `before_action`

Comment: Take note of the fact that the main Rails guides page is now for Rails 4.0.0.  You should be looking at older guides if you're using an older version of Rails.

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.13, and if I change before_action ro before_filter than rails tell me that "undefined method `before_filter'"

Comment: seems like there's no filters for ActionMailer in Rails 3 =(

Comment: One possible workaround is to do it in the initializer: http://thepugautomatic.com/2012/08/sendgrid-metadata-and-rails/

Comment: @barba There's a way to implement this now. Refer accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565784/before-filter-in-action-mailer-rails-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no callbacks for ActionMaler::Base in Rails 3

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar?

Comment: @BrianArmstrong There's a way to implement this now. Refer accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565784/before-filter-in-action-mailer-rails-3

Answer (score 1):

Check the beginning of your controller. Had a similar error where this...

```
  before_action :set_org, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

got moved to above this accidently...

```
class OrgsController < ApplicationController
```

Move it back inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
include AbstractController::Callbacks
```

in your mailer class and use `before_filter`

See this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565784/before-filter-in-action-mailer-rails-3#answer-19858338)