# Before filter in action mailer Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback, actionmailer, before-filter

***What I need:***

Something similar to before_filter in ActionMailer in Rails 3.

***Problem:***

I am working on Rails 3 and want to have a before_filter in ActionMailer. Checked the [actionmailer api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) and learned about before_action and after_action callbacks. When implemented it gives the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `before_action' for Notifier:Class
```

Later learned that there is no before action call for Rails 3 from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470969/undefined-method-before-action-for-actionmailer)

Isnt there any hook or gem so that we can have something similar like before_filter in Rails 3.

Please help. Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can be achieved by including AbstractController::Callbacks. This mimics the change to Rails 4 which apart from comments and tests, just included Callbacks.

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include AbstractController::Callbacks

  after_filter :check_email

  def some_mail_action(user)
    @user = user
    ...
  end

  private
   def check_email
     if @user.email.nil?
     message.perform_deliveries = false
    end
    true
   end

end
```

Reference - [How to add a before_filter in UserMailer which checks if it is OK to mail a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594626/how-to-add-a-before-filter-in-usermailer-which-checks-if-it-is-ok-to-mail-a-user)

Comment: Warning, on rails 3 (verified this w/ ActionMailer 3.2.21), calling "mail" in your after_filter invokes ActionMailer::Base#mail again. "mail", as of 3.2.21, isn't designed to be called repeatedly: some of the information you passed in the first time will be sticky (body for example) while other information is not (subject for example). It's safer and more reliable to refer to "message" instead of "mail". In the case above, "mail.perform_deliveries = false" gets the job done (prevents the mail from going out) but it also has side effects (resets the subject to default, etc.).